# Letsencrypt Wildcard certficate with NFS. [U 18.04]

Tags: ubuntu, wildcards, nfs, reverse-proxy, letsencrypt

I'm currently trying to share and use my wildcard certificate from letsencrypt with NFS, but the servers who are supposed to use it, cannot do so.

To my Setup:
I have 3 VM's (in future maybe 4) running.
One is a Reverse-proxy, that receives all http and https traffic and redirects them to my Mail server and my Kanboard.
My mailserver runs with iRedMail.

My problem is that I fail to deploy the certificate on both, the Kanboard and the iRedMail server.
Kanboard (APACHE2) tells me this:

```
SSLCertificateFile: file '/mnt/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty
```

and iRedMail (NGINX) this:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail.crt'
```

Since I dont want this post to drag to long, I created some pastebins with my configs, and things I have done.
[Reverse-proxy](https://pastebin.com/dqD1JW5i), [iRedMail](https://pastebin.com/kb6y2hFf), [Kanboard](https://pastebin.com/KurAMdJ9) : All will be accessible for 6 months.

HTTPS access for domain.com (meaning Reverse-Proxy) works without a problem.

Output for *sudo ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/* (live)

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 administrator root 4096 Feb 13 16:25 live
```

All 3 Servers run Ubuntu 1804 Server and the user "administrator" uses the same credentials.

If you need anymore information, feel free to ask.
**Edits**

1. [Outputs for namei -lx /path/to/private/key](https://pastebin.com/gCp0J55X)

Comment: What output do you get for `namei -lx /path/to/private/key` on each server?

Comment: DId you run the above daemons as root? Did you `use no_root_squash` on NFS server?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick replies. @muru I added a link to a pastebin with all outputs to the original post. @Romeo - I run the systemctl start commands with sudo if you mean this. And I did not use the `use no_root_squash` in my export config file. Please correct me if I am on the wrong track.

Comment: @Zockerjonny if you didn't use `no_root_squash`, the default `root_squash` takes effect, so access as root from the client is treated as from access from some other user on the server. As you can see in the `namei` output, at least some directories are only accessibly by root.

Comment: @muru adding the root_squash enabled both servers to use the Certificate. Thanks!

Comment: @muru Sorry, failed to edit my comment in time. Now I only have a problem with Reverse-Proxy and Certificates (Local resolution works, domain.com doesn't. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED or in FF PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR). But thats probably a question for the "Server Fault" right? Also should add the solution to the original post, since I cannot mark comments as Solution (atleast I dont see how).

Comment: You can post an answer explaining what you did, or @RomeoNinov can, since they suggested `no_root_squash` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the daemons in list run as root (mail and web listen on port <1024) and those daemons try to read from NFS they will have problem because usually NFS shares are done w/o option no_root_squash. The idea is NFS map local (on client) root user as anonymous user with ID not 0. And local root user will have no access to NFS shared files and directories with restricted permissions only for root. So the OP can resolve this issue using two ways:

1. change permissions of files and directories so world can read the files.

or

2. add no_root_squash to the NFS share (and restart NFS server)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @muru and @RomeoNinov I was able to use the certificates with a small adjustment to my NFS-Server. Since my Pastebins are limited to 6 months I'll post my config here.

I am still using NFS to share my Certificates across the Network

> sudo nano */etc/exports* opens my config and in the last line I used the following before `/etc/letsencrypt IP-OF-REVERSE-PROXY (rw,sync,no_subtree_check)` I simply added `no_root_squash` at the end `(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)`.

After a restart of all servers I checked if the services were running - they did. I went into the browser and checked the local-IPs to have a look at the certificates, all were correct.
I also edited `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` after reading [no_root_squash](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sect-security_guide-securing_nfs-do_not_use_the_no_root_squash_option) to limit the access to my NFS-share allowing the 3 servers to access my share, allowing my Admin-PC remote access via SFTP and SSH and denying everything else. [Hosts.allow NFS](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/access-denied-for-nfs-but-hosts-allow-and-hosts-deny-seem-ok-907291/)